# Live Video Chat app in iOS for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, video-streaming, livechat

I wanted to develop an app with live video chat just like Skype or Tango. I have search a lot over the internet but could not found any helpful answer.
Basically what I want to do is only two peoples communicate with each other through live video chat.

If you have any helpful answer please post below so that I can move forward in my project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to follow given Link 
[Sample demo for video chat](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios)

i hope this will help you great.

If you any queries about this sample demo than comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Use parse  framework for video chat.

It is very easy to implement.

You will get all information in parse website.

[How To write your first iPhone Video Chat App using parse and opentok(tokbox)](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-tutorial-create-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try this.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you please give it up votes or mark it as answer and if you have any query related to this comment here.

Comment: I hope this will help you my answer.

Comment: Is it my answer is helpfull for you than plz accept so it will be helpfull for others...